# How can I replace a javascript function of a website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to modify a websites javascript function:

```
function example(pExample) {
  ...
}
```

to:

```
function example(pExample) {
  ...
  console.log(pExample);
}
```

I've already tried to change the said function in Chrome Dev Tools Sources Tab after it got loaded, but it seems like the changes have no effect. I already thought of replacing the source of the script with my own script using some kind of extension, but the script changes its name on every page reload, so I don't think that's possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `example` global? Or, where is it called? A specific example of a site (or the full HTML/JS of a [MCVE]) with a function would help a lot. There are a few techniques, but it depends on the circumstances

Comment: I am not very sure, please have a look at https://paste.ee/p/FRdBe, the said function is _SocketSend() , it get's called by some weird webAssembly functions.

Comment: 25,000 lines is not exactly a [MCVE], but the function is not scoped to the window, so it'll be harder. Maybe overwrite `UnityLoader["c587df8d22291646f86723dddaa0eb1c"]` with your own un-assignable object before this part of the script runs

Comment: I am very sorry. But how can I overwrite it before it runs, when it instantly runs after the script loads?

Comment: Probably with MutationObserver, but it's hard to say what exactly the code would be without seeing the HTML

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try. I think I am way to unexperienced tho, do you also give paid help?

Comment: I could, but I'd be happy just to answer the question here if there's a [MCVE] to look at

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The files name is different on every reload, and I can't find a reference to this name anywhere. I don't know how to change the function before it gets loaded into memory. Can we talk somewhere else?

Comment: I'm about to go to sleep, but if you're interested enough I'll check back here tomorrow, maybe we can go to a chatroom

Comment: Alright, sounds good. See you later.

Comment: The generic solution is to use Fiddler or a similar MitM proxy tool to alter the response before the browser sees it. The alternatives are a) WebExtension in Firefox - it can change the network response before it's parsed by the browser; b) chrome extension using [Fetch.enable](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch#method-enable) via chrome.debugger API.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an interrupt point just before the function is called, and from the console overwrite the function.

[image]

Comment: Even when I put a breakpoint at the function itself, it won't break. Looks like the script gets loaded into memory somehow, that's probably because I can't just modify the file.

Comment: I believe that once loaded into memory you cannot modify a file directly from devTools, you can only interrupt its loading into memory by adding breakpoints, and overwrite the functions before they are executed (reload after adding the breakpoints)

Comment: The problem is, that on every reload, the files name changes, so the breakpoint is lost.

Comment: In that case you can't prevent the function from running with the original code, you can overwrite it  (if it's a global function)  and run it again with your new code, but it won't prevent a first execution.